# web workers: how to know if the browser supports it?

Tags: javascript, html

What's the best way to know if the running browser supports web-workers ?

is it

```
try { new Worker(); } catch (e) { /* it does not */ }
```

Thanks

Comment: `new Worker`, not `new WebWorker`, and it takes an argument - http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the code the script [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) uses:

```
tests[webWorkers] = function () {
    return !!window.Worker;
};
```

Comment: A bit naive (I bet I have pages that define something called `Worker` in some of my older stuff), but...

Comment: Dive into HTML5 suggests the same code (see http://diveintohtml5.org/everything.html). @T.J.: would your thing called `Worker` end up on the `window` object though?

Comment: @Paul: Yes. If you declare a `var` at page scope, it becomes a property of `window`. My early stuff, like a lot of early stuff (and even a lot of stuff today) declared lots of `var`s at page scope. (Now I use a scoping function so most of my stuff exposes no public symbols at all.)

Comment: The funny thing is that it will raise exception when called inside some worker (`window` undefined).

Answer (score 3):

You can try `window.Worker` in your browser's console to check if the function exists.
In your javascript code you can try this:

```
if (typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
   //great, your browser supports web workers
} else {
   //not supported
}
```

Comment: This solved the problem and gives correct vlaues